# Android Volley how to post array of custom object

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I'm new to volley and i need to post an array of custom object to PHP api in order to save it in MYSQL database how can i accomplish this ?

Note :  I know that my below code will pass only the last object of my array only

Here is my object  :

```
public class object {

String name;
Integer qty;
Integer price;
}
```

and my code  :

```
final ArrayList<object> myarray = new ArrayList<>();
        myarray.add(ob1);
        myarray.add(ob2);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject jsonArray = new JSONObject();
        try {
            int i = 0;
            for (object obj : myarray) {

                jsonArray.put("id",i++);
                jsonArray.put("name",obj.name);
                jsonArray.put("qty",obj.qty);
                jsonArray.put("price",obj.price);
            }
            Log.i("JSON ARRAY ", jsonArray.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                return params;
            }
        }; queue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: check your backend/php response . i suspecting that's wrong

Comment: Check at your server end and response

Comment: @SathishKumarJ  My first issue is my code posting only 1 object not the entire array this is my question

Answer (score 1):

Need to add your `JSONObject` to `JSONArray` for every loop like,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

int i = 0;
  for (object obj : myarray) {
     JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject();
     jsonObj.put("id", i++);
     jsonObj.put("name", nameStr);
     jsonObj.put("qty", qtyStr);
     jsonObj.put("price", priceStr);

     jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

}

Log.i("JSON ARRAY ", jsonArray.toString());
```

this may helps you.

Comment: after changing to your code the JsonArray is `["{\"id\":0,\"name\":\"item1\",\"qty\":2,\"price\":334}","{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"item2\",\"qty\":4,\"price\":399}"]` why is that ?